# React batching commit phase across renders

Tags: reactjs, render, draw

I've looked far and wide and can't find the answer to this:

Use case is scrolling a mouse wheel to zoom in.
Every time the wheel is moved a notch, an update is issued with a new level of zoom.
If a new setState is called before the previous one is finished and displayed, it will start processing the next call. However, react will not display the results of the previous render on the screen!

So, if i molest the scroll wheel, it will push dozens of render calls before actually showing anything on the screen, causing very poor user experience. (Here's the video: https://youtu.be/YRVK8uoVml0)

I don't know hot to force it to draw each render on screen.

And please, not answers like "You shouldn't be doing that", or "Just fire one update at a time". Only answer if you actually know the answer. Thank you.

Comment: Seems you should throttle the scroll handler so it only invokes/updates once per X unit of time regardless of wheel molestation. This is a common solution with scroll handlers, BTW.

Comment: Tried it, works pretty well. Thanx! I'm still curious about the react policy on redraws though..